# REG ADD REG_SZ where Value contains embedded double quotes

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, windows-registry

This is driving me bananas but it must be something very simple.  I am trying to add an ImagePath Value (REG_SZ) in a Batch script using REG ADD, where the Value Data contains embedded "double quotes". But I keep getting an "Invalid Syntax" error. This is the Value I am trying to add:

```
Key  : HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
Value: ImagePath REG_SZ
Data : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sSQLEXPRESS
```

I tried enclosing the Data in single quotes:

```
@SETLOCAL
@SET IPATH="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sSQLEXPRESS
@REG.EXE ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS" /f /v ImagePath /t REG_SZ /d '%IPATH%'
```

I also tried enclosing in "double quotes", bang (!), [brackets], \backslashes\ and ^carets^ but I keep getting the syntax error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter needs to be double-quoted. Other randomly chosen punctuation (single quotes, exclamation marks, ...) is not going to work.

However, you need to prefix the *inner* double-quotes with backslashes:

```
@SET ImagePath=\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe\" -sSQLEXPRESS
@REG.EXE ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS" /f /v ImagePath /t REG_SZ /d "%ImagePath%"
```

Note 1: To assign values in Cmd you need to use `SET` (as in `SET VAR=VALUE`).

Note 2: Do not use `PATH` as the variable name, as it is already used by Cmd for specifying program locations and overwriting it will make the script unable to run `REG.EXE`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo and PATH misuse - fixed.

Comment: your answer made me realize that I did not post the question properly. Rather than an extensive redo, I will create a new question. Should I delete this one?

Comment: Question has been replaced by [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1464364/reg-add-reg-sz-where-value-contains-embedded-double-quotes-redux)