# REG ADD REG_SZ where Value contains embedded double quotes (redux)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, windows-registry

This is driving me bananas but it must be something very simple.  I am trying to modify an ImagePath Value (REG_SZ) for a Service in a Batch script using REG ADD, where the Value Data contains embedded "double quotes". But I keep getting an "Invalid Syntax" error. This is the Value I am trying to add:

```
Key  : HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\myservice
Value: ImagePath REG_SZ
Data : "c:\program files\mydir\old.exe" -helloworld
```

I am trying to change the ImagePath to:

```
Data: "c:\program files\mydir\new.exe" -helloworld
```

However I am getting a Syntax Error in the REG ADD command. This is the stripped down script:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
for /f "tokens=2*" %%A in ('REG.EXE QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\myservice" /v ImagePath') DO set IPATHOLD=%%B
SET IPATHOLD=%IPATHOLD:\0= %
echo OLDPATH^=%IPATHOLD%
set "OLDEXE=old.exe"
set "NEWEXE=new.exe"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ("%IPATHOLD%") do (
    set "string=%%A"
    set "IPATHNEW=!string:%OLDEXE%=%NEWEXE%!"
)
echo NEWPATH^=%IPATHNEW%
@echo on
@pause
if !IPATHNEW! NEQ !IPATHOLD! (
    @echo ready to change
    @REM next line results in Syntax Error
    REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\myservice" /v ImagePath /t REG_SZ /d "%IPATHNEW%" /f
)
```

I have tried enclosing `%IPATHNEW%` in "doublequotes", 'singlequotes', [brackets] and \backslashes\ but I keep getting the syntax error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

(Note - this is a replacement of this question:
[REG ADD REG_SZ where Value contains embedded double quotes](https://superuser.com/questions/1464332/reg-add-reg-sz-where-value-contains-embedded-double-quotes))

Comment: Do you have to use a Cmd batch script specifically, rather than PowerShell or VBScript?

Comment: PowerShell should be fine, although I am much less familiar with PowerShell than CMD script. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are looking for is probably the one that will replace `"` by `\"`:

```
    set "IPATHNEW=!IPATHNEW:"=^\"!"
```

The script might look like this:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
for /f "tokens=2*" %%A in ('REG.EXE QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\myservice" /v ImagePath') DO set IPATHOLD=%%B
set "IPATHNEW=!IPATHOLD:old=new!"
set "IPATHNEW=!IPATHNEW:"=^\"!"
echo "%IPATHNEW%"
@pause
if !IPATHNEW! NEQ !IPATHOLD! (
    REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\myservice" /v ImagePath /t REG_SZ /d "%IPATHNEW%" /f
)
```

I tested it partially and it seemed to work.

Comment: One other question. How do I check `!IPATHOLD!` to see if it actually contains the string `old` before proceeding?  I played around with various `IF` scenarios but kept getting "not expected now" errors.

Comment: This might need a new question, fully documented. Drop me a note if you want me to have a look.